Is it NP-hard to decide whether a graph is balanced bipartite?
The problem is the following. On input, an undirected graph $G = (V, E)$. Question: can $V$ be partitioned into two (disjoint) subsets $V = V_1 \cup V_2$, with $-1 \leq |V_1| - |V_2| \leq 1$ so that the graph $(V_1, V_2, E)$ is bipartite?
Alternative formulation #1: can a graph be partitioned into two balanced independent sets?
Alternative formulation #2: can a graph be 2-colored with balanced color classes?
Is it NP-hard? I am looking for a reference to a proof of NP-hardness (or a polynomial-time algorithm).

The problem is in $\mathsf{P}$. Indeed, let us denote $G_1 = (C_1, E_1)$, …, $G_k = (C_k, E_k)$ the connected components of $G$.
For each $1\leqslant i \leqslant k$, let $v_i \in C_i$ be an arbitrary vertex. If there is a bipartition $(V_1, V_2)$ of $G$, then $\{v\in C_i \mid \text{dist}(v_i, v) \text{ is even}\}\subseteq V_1$ and $\{v\in C_i \mid \text{dist}(v_i, v) \text{ is odd}\}\subseteq V_2$, or the converse.
Let $a_i = \lvert \lvert \{v\in C_i \mid \text{dist}(v_i, v) \text{ is even}\}\lvert - \lvert \{v\in C_i \mid \text{dist}(v_i, v) \text{ is odd}\}\lvert \lvert$.
Then there is a balanced bipartition if and only if $G$ is bipartite and there exists $I\subseteq [\![1,k]\!]$ such that:
$$\left| \sum\limits_{i\in I}a_i -\sum\limits_{i\notin I}a_i\right| \leqslant 1$$
There is a polynomial time algorithm solving this problem (since $\max a_i \leqslant |V|$).
